# Google Custom Function : error Invalid assignment left-hand side

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I've created a custom google spreadsheet function via the script editor that calculates pace. I call the function in my spreadsheet via

```
=pace(00:33:00,10,km)
```

and the logic for the function is

```
function pace(time, dist, unit)
{
  return pace(time.getHours(),time.getMinutes(),time.getSeconds(), dist, unit);
}

function pace(hrs,mins,secs,dist,unit) 
{ 
  var d = dist;
  if(unit=="m"||unit="M")
    d = dist*1.609344;

  var minutes = 60*hrs+mins+secs/60.0;
  var pace = minutes/d;
  return pace;
}
```

but when the function is executed all i get is

```
error: Invalid assignment left-hand side.
```

I think the logic is correct and the issue is related to the publication status of the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

H,

It seems you are missing and equal sign in the second argument to your if statement.

```
 if(unit=="m"||unit=="M")
```